# Python how to create new dataset from an existing one based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

For example:
I have this code:

```
import pandas
df = pandas.read_csv('covid_19_data.csv')
```

this dataset has a column called `countryterritoryCode` which is the country code of the country.[sample data from the dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hlCC.png)

This dataset has information about covid19 cases from all the countries in the world.
How do I create a new dataset where only the USA info appears
(where `countryterritoryCode == USA`)

Answer (score 3):

```
import pandas
df = pandas.read_csv('covid_19_data.csv')
new_df = df[df["country"] == "USA"]
or
new_df = df[df.country == "USA"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`df.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
df = pandas.read_csv('covid_19_data.csv')

df_new = df.groupby('countryterritoryCode', axis = 1)
```